# Matrix Multiplication doesn't work

Tags: c++, matrix

Below here is my C++ code for the multiplication of 2 matrices. First input is the dimensions: so rows and columns of matrix 1 and rows and columns of matrix 2. Then you need to input all the elements of both matrices. When that is done, the 2 matrices should be multiplied and the resulting matrix should be shown. However for one reason, after I inputted all the elements, it's getting stuck. Is there someone of you understand what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix_functions.hpp"

using namespace std;    

int read_matrix(int** matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new int[cols];
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cin >> matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    return **matrix;
} 

int print_matrix(int** result, int rows, int cols)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cout << result[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout << endl;

    return **result;
}

int multiply_matrix(int** matrix, int rows, int cols, int** matrix1, int rows1, int    cols1, int** result)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols1; j++)
        {
            result[i][j] = 0;

            for(int k = 0; k < cols; k++)
            {
                result[i][j] = result[i][j] + (matrix[i][k] * matrix1[k][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    return **result;
 }

int main ()
{
    //matrices and dimensions
    int rows1, cols1, rows2, cols2;
    int **matrix1, **matrix2, **result = 0;

    cout << "Enter matrix dimensions" << endl;
    cin >> rows1 >> cols1 >> rows2 >> cols2;

    cout << "Enter a matrix" << endl;

    matrix1 = new int*[rows1];

    // Read values from the command line into a matrix
    read_matrix(matrix1, rows1, cols1);

    cout << "Enter a matrix" << endl;

     matrix2 = new int*[rows2];

    read_matrix(matrix2, rows2, cols2);

    // Multiply matrix1 one and matrix2, and put the result in matrix result
    multiply_matrix(matrix1, rows1, cols1, matrix2, rows2, cols2, result);

    print_matrix(result, rows1, cols2);

    //TODO: free memory holding the matrices

    return 0;
}
```

Also, right now, my matrix gets printed as a 1d horizontal vector (1 2 3 4) rather than a matrix (1 2 and 3 4 below that). Anyone can explain me how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: You don't need to write your own matrix multiply and I/O. Try using ublas from the Boost C++ Libraries. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
multiply_matrix(matrix1, rows1, cols1, matrix2, rows2, cols2, result); 
`new` for result? Forgot?
```

Something like this:

```
result = new int*[rows1];
for(int i = 0; i < rows1; i++)
{
   result[i] = new int[cols2];
}
multiply_matrix(matrix1, rows1, cols1, matrix2, rows2, cols2, result);
```

You haven't allocated memory for `result` matrix.
Hence you're a victim of undefined behavior.

Regarding printing in matrix form you need to print newline.

There is no need to return the elements from the read and multiply functions.

Also, check the validity for the multiplication of two matrices i.e `cols1 == rows2` before multiplying.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I dont use malloc, i use new. I did this:

Comment: matrix1 = new int*[rows1];
matrix2 = new int*[rows2];
result  = new int*[rows1];

Comment: My matrices get multiplied well. Only problem: after multiplying and showing the matrix, it still crashes. How can I solve this?

Comment: Thank you. Indeed it worked :) One question: WHY does it work? I mean i dont really understand what the problem was, and how does this fix that?

Comment: @Earless: `result` was not allocated any memory, and moreover you had initialized it to `0`. So, you were starting from possibly address `0` and doing all the multiply operations. This could be fatal most of the times since that un-allocated address might be used by some other process or application and access it produces nightmares! In other words the standard says that it leads to `undefined behavior` when you access unallocated memory. Look up for undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining. But I still dont understand why you wrote that particular piece of code. Why would you go in a for loop for allocating the memory, and why the result[i] = new int[cols2] ??

Comment: Other than that. thank you very much. My code is done, and it works:D

Answer (score 0):

If you want the matrix printed on different lines, then print a newline character.  The C++ way to do this is with std::endl.

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        cout << result[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl; ///< ADD THIS LINE
}
```

Comment: @Ben, added text explanation per your request.